# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined - using greater than operator in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

this is a weird one. Please look at the following php:

```
$time = 1234;
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT order_id, expiry FROM installs WHERE upd_code = ? AND expiry > ?');
$query->bindParam(1, $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(2, $time, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

Produces the error:

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

This only happens when I use a greater than operator for some reason. < or = doesn't produce an error. Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you run *exactly* the same code when getting this error message? Are you 100% positively sure? What if you run a query like this: `"SELECT ?, 1 > ?"`

Comment: Are you sure this is the *right* query that throws an error? Do you have aline number with error message? Does the number match?

Comment: Yes this is the exact code and yes this is the query it fails on. Basically, where ever I use a greater than operator it fails in the same way. If I use '=' or '<' instead of '>' it works without any errors. I cannot understand it - I have tried two different server installations as well.

Comment: if I run SELECT ?, 1 > ? I get the same error btw

Comment: Is it **clear** PDO installation or some homebrewed class extending it?

Comment: Please add `$query->debugDumpParams();` output to your question. And make sure its the right query throws this error

Comment: Thanks loads for your help the debug didn't point to that query, as you suspected. Upon execution of the query above - it triggered some other distant code where the true problem was. Simply by removing the first query stopped the execution of the actual query causing the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of all the try-catch blocks in your code, whose only purpose is to echo the `$e->getMessage()` out.

If you only had this thing the right way already, there would be no question at all. Because PHP can handle exceptions better than average PHP user, adding, for example, exact file name and **line number** where the error occurred - so, it would make you aware of the real cause immediately, making all the wrong assumptions and guesswork of no use.

Comment: So you're saying it's bad practice to use try / catch? I can understand your point over php being more specific than $e->getMessage() but surely dealing with errors gracefully is the better approach? Maybe try / catch should be utilised after the code is finalised?

Comment: What do you call "gracefully"?

Comment: As in don't display a php error to the end user but instead do something else as a reaction to an error caught in the try block. Not sure how else I could do that gracefully? Is there a better way I'm missing here?

Comment: one single line `ini_set('display_errors',0);` will remove all the error messages (Not only ones you caught, but all of them - mind you!) from the public view. Without writing hundreds of try-catch blocks. Without taking them back when you need to debug your code again.

Comment: no I know that but I need to actuate a code path if something fails hence the need to try / catch - is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: I've told you already. If your only idea of using try-catch is to just $e->getMessage() out - just get rid of it. It has nothing to do with graceful error handling.

Comment: Fair enough, but what is the best practice for graceful error handling?

Comment: If you want to handle the error *itself* - no problem with try-catch. But if you want to handle only error message (like you do in your code at the moment) - create a custom exception handler and write all the handling code there. Or - better - let PHP handle it.